# How to line in 1/8in cable on Samsung Galaxy 7

Tags: audio, bluetooth

So, my end goal is this: I want to take audio input from a 3.5mm audio cable, which is outputting sound, send it through the headphone plug into a phone, and transmit to a pair of bluetooth headphones. The phone is a samsung galaxy 7, the headphones are a pair of JBL Free, and I can't remember if the 3.5mm has 3 or 4 poles. Does this sound doable?

Comment: @NordlysJeger That's strange. When making the stackexchange account, I clicked the option that said 'Software or hardware issues' and it directed me here. I'll check out the android SE

Comment: maybe I just misunderstood and your question is actually about Computer hardware which would be the right place here. Maybe you could explain what exactly you tried and which hardware/software you used to do that

Comment: 1) Is your cable the standard 3.5mm four-connector plug ? https://static.rapidonline.com/catalogueimages/product/s51-5131p01wl.jpg Or, is a three pole plug?  https://www.canford.co.uk/Images/ItemImages/large/43-288_01.jpg 2) Is the output from your audio source into the phone line, or microphone, level? 3) Are you able to record a clean signal on your phone once connected with a recorder app? Please click on [edit] and add the answers into your question.

Comment: @NordlysJeger Done. If you have any more questions, please lemme know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue you'll encounter is that you have stereo output but only mono input (on your phones side). [Source](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec)

[image: Picture of different types of headphone jacks]

As you can see, your phone has two speaker/audio out contacts (used to stream sound e.g. music to another device e.g. speakers) no matter what type of headphone jack you plug in, but only one contact for microphone/audio in (needed to stream music to the phone).

If you plug in your typical headphone cable you only connect to the speaker connectors and not with your microphone connector.

> I want to take audio input from a 3.5mm audio cable, which is outputting sound.

If your audio source outputs only in mono you could simply dismantle a four connector cable and remap one of it's speaker contacts to the input contact.

If you want something more refined you could try something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GS17DMR) headphone jack to Bluetooth transmitter which is able to stream stereo to your headphones and probably in a much better quality.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I did know about the bluetooth transmitter, and was considering getting one. But if i can use my phone instead, it saves me $20 and 4 days in shipment time. But by the looks of what you've shown me, it doesn't seem all that practical. Again, thank you for the answer.